# Userdefaults to save switch state

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, swift3

I Have a switch that when turned to "on" will put the music and when the switch is set to "off" the music will resume playing. My problem is that when i leave the view controller the switch will appear as "off" when it is switch "on". The code for my switch is below, I'm not sure what to write in order for the app to remember the switch state, please help.

```
//
//  SecondViewController.swift
//  Urban Sphere
//
//  Created by Oren Edrich on 9/11/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Oren Edrich. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

var bombSoundEffect: AVAudioPlayer!
var Ghost = SKSpriteNode()

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var sw = false

@IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func switchpressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if mySwitch.isOn{

        if bombSoundEffect != nil {
            bombSoundEffect.stop()
            bombSoundEffect = nil   
        }
    }
    else{
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "newmusic.wav", ofType:nil)!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            bombSoundEffect = sound
            sound.numberOfLoops = -1
            sound.play()
        } catch {
            // couldn't load file :(
        }

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the correct answer and decided to post it incase anyone has the same question.

```
@IBAction func saveSwitchState(sender: AnyObject) {
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if bluetoothSwitch.on {
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "SwitchState")
} else {
    defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "SwitchState")
}
}
```

and...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if (defaults.objectForKey("SwitchState") != nil) {
    bluetoothSwitch.on = defaults.boolForKey("SwitchState")
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want know where to insert the code , I guess.

---

updata

---

updata2
Then you can run directly. If it's useful , please UP this answer.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

        static let bombSoundEffect = {()->(AVAudioPlayer) in

            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "newmusic.wav", ofType:nil)!
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            return try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        }()

        var sw = false

        var Ghost = SKSpriteNode()


        @IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch!

        @IBAction func switchpressed() {

            if mySwitch.isOn{

                SecondViewController.bombSoundEffect.play()
            }else{

                SecondViewController.bombSoundEffect.stop()
            }

            //*************    save status    *************
            UserDefaults.standard.set(mySwitch.isOn, forKey: "SwitchStatus");


        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()



            mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchpressed), for: .valueChanged)

            //*************    load status    *************
            mySwitch.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SwitchStatus");
            switchpressed()

        }



    }
```

Comment: Would you be able to show how my code would look, i don't know how to enter in your code with what my code looks like.

Comment: i am getting an error with "bombSoundEffect" under the "CheckSwitchStatus" Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation to yours, and I just use UserDefaults. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do it.

1. Create a variable like the following example. This will set the default setting and store the state of the check box for use later:

   ```
   var musicSetting = UserDefaults().string(forKey: "Music") ?? "On"
   ```
2. In your `viewDidLoad`, add an if statement that will check whether the Check Box should be On or Off, like this:

   ```
   if musicSetting == "On" {
       theNameOfYourSwitch.isOn = false
   } else {
       theNameOfYourSwitch.isOn = true
   }
   ```
3. In the `IBAction` property for your check box, add an if statement like the following that will save your Setting, depending on what it is:

   ```
   if theNameOfYourCheckbox.state == NSOnState {
       UserDefaults().set("On", forKey: "Music")
   } else {
       UserDefaults().set("Off", forKey: "Music")
   }
   ```

Here's a screenshot that might help:
[image: image here...]

Comment: Is it simply not saving the state? Or are you getting an error? Either one could be a simple solution.

Comment: It is not saving the state

Comment: Would be able to show how my coding should look with the saving switch feature

Comment: I made an edit to my answer which simply swaps the "Yes" and "No" around in step 3. Sometimes that does the trick. Let me know if it works.

Comment: What do i change the ".state" to?

Comment: @OrenEdrich to make it easier for both of us, I'll upload a screenshot of what your code should look like. I won't be able to do it right away (may be a couple days), but I'll get to it as soon as I can. 

Comment: That would be perfect

Comment: I saw that you had accepted my answer, then un-accepted it. Could you please let me know if you still need a screenshot of the code?

Comment: I was able to get the switch to save partially, so i still need your screenshot

Comment: Just updated my answer. Just realized that you're working with switches, not checkboxes. Sorry about that confusion. I tested this code and it works no problem for me. Let me know how it goes :-)

Comment: Where would i type in the code i want the switch to do when it is pressed?

Comment: You would need to type it in the IBAction property of the switch.

Comment: the switch always appears on

Comment: Maybe I'll make a video that I can post on YouTube. That might help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124835/discussion-between-tdm-and-oren-edrich).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the state of Switch in user default, then can use the 
native method

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(_ value: Bool, forKey defaultName: String)
```

Like this

```
    UserDefaults.standard.set(mySwitch.isOn, forKey: "SwitchStatus");
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
```

While fetching switch status just use

```
    let status = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SwitchStatus");
```

UPDATE :

```
@IBAction func switchpressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

UserDefaults.standard.set(mySwitch.isOn, forKey: "SwitchStatus");

if mySwitch.isOn{

    if bombSoundEffect != nil {
        bombSoundEffect.stop()
        bombSoundEffect = nil
    }
}
else{
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "newmusic.wav", ofType:nil)!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        bombSoundEffect = sound
        sound.numberOfLoops = -1
        sound.play()
    } catch {
        // couldn't load file :(
    }
}
}
```

Hope it helps

Happy coding ...

Comment: Where should i be putting this line of code "UserDefaults.standard.set(_ value: Bool, forKey defaultName: String)"

Comment: There is no need to call `synchronize` each time you update user defaults

Comment: I just eded the question show the full code in my view controller, can you update your answer to show where i have to add in the "user defaults" code into

Comment: i entered in the exact code you wrote user "update:" and it does not work

Comment: i don't know where to put "    UserDefaults.standard.set(mySwitch.isOn, forKey: "SwitchStatus");
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();" and "UserDefaults.standard.set(_ value: Bool, forKey defaultName: String)" Can you please write what the full viewcontroller code should look like

Comment: Copy the "switchpressed" function from my answer and replace in your code. Then where you want to fetch the status of switch, just write the single "line let status =     UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SwitchStatus");"
Then in the status, you will get true/ false according to on/off of switch

Comment: It still does not save the state of the switch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124682/discussion-between-oren-edrich-and-janmenjaya).